# Will magento remain open source after adobe acquire magento

Tags: magento2

I Heard news today that adobe is acquiring Magento. Below is the link from adobe.

[Adobe to Acquire Magento Commerce](http://news.adobe.com/press-release/corporate/adobe-acquire-magento-commerce)

Now my concern is that magento will remain open source or in future we will see

paid version. I am talking about magento community version.

Comment: Right now it is early to say but in my opinion it will remain open source

Comment: Agree with @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: We are collecting predictions and thinking about the situation with live updates https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-magento-adobe-acquisition-its-impact-on-the-ecosystem.html

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Magento will remain open source check this tweet

https://twitter.com/mjasay/status/998930665805496321

**First Day Thought**

Right now  its early to say , but after reading below blog on adobe site

we can say that MagentoCE will remain opensource

https://medium.com/adobe-io/doubling-down-on-adobes-open-platform-vision-with-magento-c9f8246e83e2

https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/adobe-to-acquire-magento